# Does --deploy-url adjust the base Url dynamically if an Angular app is served from a CDN?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, cdn

We have an angular app which we wanna build once and deploy to multiple environments. We wanna serve this app through CDNs, which we have setup for each environment, the base URL for these CDNs are unknown at build time and need to be set dynamically based on the environment during runtime. The build assets are deployed to the following 'dist' subfolder on the CDN.

```
--{root}
  |--static
     |--dist
```

We are providing the `--deploy-url=static/dist` argument to angular CLI during build time.

now, if the URL for our environment is `https://qa.example.com`
and the base URL for the CDN for this environment is `https://qa-cdn.example.com`

Assuming that we have served the initial bundles i.e. `main.js` and `runtime.js` successfully from the CDN i.e. `https://qa-cdn.example.com/static/dist/`. Will the lazy chunks and other assets like images load from the CDN as well? i.e. while looking for these lazy chunks and assets, will Webpack resolve the deploy URL to be `https://qa-cdn.example.com/static/dist/` or `https://qa.example.com/static/dist/`?

P.S. - Unfortunately, our application is not a SPA and setting or modifying the `<base />` tag is not an option (if that could even help us in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (and experience) is that the `--deploy-url` should be set to the cdn url. The lazy loaded modules, assets etc will also load from here. The base url (base-href) won't change unless you specify what it should be during the build as a flag or in the `angular.json` file

There's also a `--base-href` flag you can set at build time.... which would seem to be `static/dist` given your example (but this doesn't look right to me here)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yes, I'm aware of the ```background-image: url(../../assets/img.png)``` being manipulated at build time when providing ```--deploy-url``` and that is not an issue for us. The only thing that I wasn't sure about is if the final URL (during runtime) for ```--deploy-url``` provided above in the question would resolve to ```https://qa-cdn.example.com/static/dist/``` instead of ```https://qa.example.com/static/dist/```? But, it seems from your answer that it will, so I appreciate you clarifying that for me. Thanks! :)